# How do I configure group policies using C#?

Tags: c#, taskmanager, gpo, controlpanel

How can I manipulate group policy based restriction for the controlpanel and the taskmanager in C#?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? It sounds like a group policy thing. Or are you asking "how do I configure group policy using C#?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WMI.  Here is a link to an article on WMI Group policy objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375082(VS.85).aspx

This tool will generate example c# code for you:
[WMICodeCreator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Registry key to restriction task manager and control panel easily!

Answer (score 0):

There is some information on how to edit GPO Registry settings available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374274(v=VS.85).aspx

There is also a good blog post here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsadsi/working-with-group-policy-objects-programmatically-simple-c-example-illustrating-how-to-modify-a-registry-based-policy)

The examples are in C++ but some clever person may be able to write a .net wrapper.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a programming question, but a question of workstation policy management. Start looking at e.g. [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/910203).