# disable online driver search on windows 7 programatically

Tags: winapi, windows-7, device-driver

I am working on a program that requires to install a driver for Plug and Play. My issue is that the first time the device plugs into, by default, windows 7 32-bit automatically search online for drivers that better match to device. As i observe, it takes too long (15m) to correctly install the driver.

How can i turn off the automatic search on windows 7?

Thank you for any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you do this through GPO, as described here:
http://www.verboon.info/index.php/2010/12/windows-7-device-installation-without-administrative-rights/

Look for "Prevent Clients from searching for drivers on Windows Update" on this page.

Read up on applying GPO programatically and you should probably be able to get the job done. However, mind that you'd be changing the policy for the whole system, not just installation of this device.

Comment: Here is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981010/how-do-i-configure-group-policy-using-c) to edit GPO in C++

Answer (score 1):

If you install a driver package for your driver before you insert it, Windows will not search online.

If you really want to disable online serach on your machine - take a look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730606%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Anchor2).

Comment: Windows Update is not checked for drivers in the Driver Store?

Comment: I found in Group Policy that the settings you mentioned don't support windows7. In help section, it says that "NOTE: This setting is replaced by "Specify Driver Source Search Order" in "Administrative Templates/System/Device Installation" on newer versions of Windows.".